# How do I update new markers of selected place types ..?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, drag, google-places

I have created a custom Google map, to show different types of places. When I click on a `checkbox` menu item in the list (see HTML). It places markers of that type within a radius of 20000 m (20 km) from the center of the map.
Now when I drag the map to a new location, how can I update the radius value from the new center location and then request for the place types in that area. 
Place types would be fetched from the `checkbox`es that are already selected.

This should repeated every time I drag the map to a new location.

I am providing the HTML and JS code below for reference:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a>Health</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a> <input type="checkbox" class="map-checkbox" id="dentist" name="dentist" value="dentist" /> Dentist</a></li>
            <li><a> <input type="checkbox" class="map-checkbox" id="doctor" name="doctor" value="doctor" /> Doctor</a></li>
            <li><a> <input type="checkbox" class="map-checkbox" id="gym" name="gym" value="gym" /> Gymnasium</a></li>
            <li><a> <input type="checkbox" class="map-checkbox" id="health" name="health" value="health" /> Health</a></li>
            <li><a> <input type="checkbox" class="map-checkbox" id="hospital" name="hospital" value="hospital" /> Hospital</a></li>
            <li><a> <input type="checkbox" class="map-checkbox" id="pharmacy" name="pharmacy" value="pharmacy" /> Pharmacy</a></li>         
         </ul> 
     <li><a>Travel</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a> <input type="checkbox" class="map-checkbox" id="airport" name="airport" value="airport" /> Airport</a>
            <li><a> <input type="checkbox" class="map-checkbox" id="bus_station" name="bus_station" value="bus_station" /> Bus Station</a></li>
            <li><a> <input type="checkbox" class="map-checkbox" id="car_rental" name="car_rental" value="car_rental" /> Car Rental</a></li>
            <li><a> <input type="checkbox" class="map-checkbox" id="subway_station" name="subway_station" value="subway_station" /> Subway Station</a></li>
            <li><a> <input type="checkbox" class="map-checkbox" id="taxi_stand" name="taxi_stand" value="taxi_stand" /> Taxi Stand</a></li> 
            <li><a> <input type="checkbox" class="map-checkbox" id="train_station" name="train_station" value="train_station" /> Train Station</a></li>
            <li><a> <input type="checkbox" class="map-checkbox" id="travel_agency" name="travel_agency" value="travel_agency" /> Travel Agency</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var loc_geocoder;
var loc_map;
var loc_marker;
var loc_image = tpl_dir + '/images/marker.png';
var placetype = [];
var selected_markers = [];

function initialize() {

//fetch lat,lng values from the post
post_location();

 // prepare Geocoder
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

//set initial position (from the post)
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('location_map'),     {
    zoom: 10,
    center: postlatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
            loc_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: postlatlng,
            title: 'CFP Roar',
            map: map,
            icon: loc_image
    });
 google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dragend',function(event) {

    clearOverlays();
    selectedMarkers();
    findPlaces(selected_markers);
    }
}

function selectedMarkers() {
 selected_markers = [];
$('.map-checkbox').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.is(':checked')){
    selected_markers.push($this.val());
        }
});
}

function clearOverlays() {
if (markers) {
    for (i in markers) {
         markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
}
function findPlaces(type) {
var radius;
var lat = document.getElementById('post_lat').value;
var lng = document.getElementById('post_lng').value;
var cur_location = map.getCenter();
var request = {
    location: cur_location,
    radius: 50000,
    types: [type]
};
if (keyword) {
    request.keyword = [keyword];
}
service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.search(request, createMarkers);
}

function createMarkers(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    // if we have found something - clear map (overlays)
    //clearOverlays();
    // and create new markers by search result
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        createMarker(results[i]);
    }
    //console.log(results);
    //$('#test').append( markers );
} else if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
    alert('Sorry, nothing is found');
}
}
function createMarker(obj) {
    var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: obj.geometry.location,
    map: map,
    title: obj.name,
marktype: placetype,
icon: gp_tpl_dir + '/gp/images/places/' + placetype + '.png'
});
     markers.push(mark);
//mark_array.push(mark);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<img src="' + obj.icon + '" /><font style="color:#000;">' + obj.name +
    '<br />Rating: ' + obj.rating + '<br />Vicinity: ' + obj.vicinity + '</font>'
});
    google.maps.event.addListener(mark, 'click', function() {
    clearInfos();
    infowindow.open(map,mark);
});
   infos.push(infowindow);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do, but perhaps look into the 'center_change' listener:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

Comment: Thanks for your support ! 
But I have tried adding a Listener the 'dragend' event,  but it only shows the latest among the array of selected types.
for example ['airport','bus_station']  places only ['bus_station'] markers after the drag event.
The problem here is to get the same (selected) markers again on a new location.

Comment: trying to understand current problem - is it that the markers are removed after the map pans? do the checkboxes reset?

Comment: Gursharan, If I understand correctly than you are trying to get new markers base on checkbox selection (which are types eg airport, bus_station) and place them on maps with new center (due to drag or zoom event) ?

Comment: Are you still trying to use a dragend event? i don't see anything for it in your code

Comment: @harmlessdragon, Sorry, that part was skipped in the code by mistake. I have added in the question above

Comment: Do you use any debugging tool? (even alert windows?) Since your problem is with the request, see if the array is complete before it enters the findPlaces method. If it is, try running the request separately from the dragend event to see if it works. I assume that when the map loads for first time, it completes the same request and works as expected? 

I tried your js for the checkboxes to retrieve selected values, and it works for me. Perhaps it's something else.

Comment: @harmlessdragon, Thanks, I solved it an hour ago. Your are right, it was a problem with the array because i was providing and array to the types property, which made an array inside an array. 
I have changed "types: [type]" to "types: type" and solved the problem.